# Formato da data em asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

Estou com problemas no formato da data em **pt-BR** em uma aplicação asp.net mvc. Onde ele exibe erro caso a data esteja no formado **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm**, e só deixa passar se a data estiver no formado **MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm**.

**Model**

```
 [Display(Name = "Data de Publicação", Description = "Selecione uma data futura para agendar uma publicação")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public System.DateTime DataPublicacao { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataPublicacao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" })
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DataPublicacao, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", htmlAttributes : new { @class = "form-control date-timepicker"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataPublicacao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript de inicialização do *datetimepicker***

```
$('.date-timepicker').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'pt-br',
            keepOpen: true,
            showTodayButton: true,
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
});
```

**Webconfig**:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @Renan infelizmente a questão o qual marcou como duplicada, nenhuma das resposta foi possível resolver o meu problema.

Comment: Erico, seria bom então editar sua pergunta para indicar isso. Coloque um link para a outra pergunta e diga que nenhuma resposta nela resolveu o seu caso.

Answer (score 3):

Eu tive o mesmo problema e o que me ajudou a resolver foi o post desse blog aqui: [MVC 3: Validação para culturas como pt-BR](https://levidad.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/mvc-3-validacao-para-culturas-como-pt-br/)

No meu projeto estou usando uma versão mais nova do ASP.NET MVC, mas mesmo assim o problema foi resolvido adicionando o script de validação.

Como sugerido pelo colega David, segue um resumão:

"Para dar suporte à validação de datas para culturas como pt-BR, é necessário adicionar um script com métodos de validação específicos."

Você pode fazer isso da seguinte forma: crie um arquivo methods_pt.js dentro da pasta Scripts do seu projeto e cole o seguinte conteúdo nele:

```
/*
 * Localized default methods for the jQuery validation plugin.
 * Locale: PT_BR
 */
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
    date: function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d?\d?$/.test(value);
    }
});
```

Mantenha no seu web.config a tag `<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />` como você mostrou na sua pergunta.

E por fim, nas páginas onde você precisar utilizar a validação, inclua os scripts como no código a seguir:

```
<!-- Scripts de validação -->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Correção de funções de validação específicas para a cultura pt-BR -->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/methods_pt.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Infelizmente, continuo com o mesmo problema. A data continua dando como inválida quando está no formado dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm.

Comment: Quando eu tive o mesmo problema da pergunta, foi isso que me resolveu pra mim também.